# Displaying message if user do not have any recipe under his name in the database

Tags: php, sql

i am a beginner with only a few weeks of experience in coding.
I am trying to implement the following feature:

If the user have any recipe under his name in the database, the recipes will be displayed in a table, i had already made his work.

However i want to display a message if the user did not have any recipe under his name in the database. Right now only a empty table appear when the user have no recipe under his name in the database.

I had tried several set of codes suggested in other similar questions by other users, but to no avail.

Many thanks!-Dom from Singapore

```html
<?php
 
 //0: Instead of hard coding I shall declare the value first
 $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    
 
 
 //1: Connect to forumdb database
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "recipedb") or exit("Error connecting to database"); 
 
 //2: Prepare the statement to select recipename belonging to the $userid from recipe table 
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select recipename,recipeid,imagefile from recipe where userid=?");


 //3: Bind the values 
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$userid);
 
 
 //4: Execute the statement
 
 $stmt->execute ();
 
 //TODO 5: bind results into $recipename
    $stmt->bind_result($recipename,$recipeid,$imagefile);
 
 
 echo "<table style=width:100% >";
 echo "<tr><td><b>Recipe</b></td><td><b>Actions</b></td></tr>";
 
 //Use while loop to fetch messages and put in a <table>
 
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
 
    echo "<tr>";
    //6: In 1st <td>, display recipename
 echo "<td><b>$recipename</b><br><b>Recipe ID:</b>$recipeid<br> <img src='images/$imagefile' >   </td>";
 
 //7: In 2nd <td>, display View hyperlink with the userid in query string.
    //The View hyperlink links to recipedetails.php
    // The delete hyperlink links to deleterecipes.php
 
 
 echo "<td> <a href='recipedetails.php?recipeid=$recipeid'>View</a>&nbsp";
 echo "<a href='messagedelete.php?recipeid=$recipeid'>Delete</a>&nbsp";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
 
 echo "</table>";
 
 //8: close the statement
 
 $stmt->close ();
 
 //9: close $mysqli
 
 $mysqli->close ();
 
 
 
 
 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a query at first which uses `Select count(ID) as amount from recipe where userid=?`

Then you have the amount of the recipes in a property/ value named `amount`. Then you can control the message